# Looking to solve radiated emission test issues (CISPR 11)

Tags: emc, radiation

We did the radiated emission test as per CISPR 11 with our device similar to tablet and observations were as below

1. When we tested with an IEC60601-1 certified adapter, many frequencies were going outside the limits.
2. To debug the problem, first we took off the adapter and ran the device only on battery, many frequencies came down, but 428 MHz and 856 MHz still went above the limit. Sometimes, even 400 MHz was also above the limit.

Our device has a board with SOC, DDR, eMMC, MIPI LCD display, MIPI camera and FPC cables to connect the display and camera to the board. The main clock is 24 MHz and the Wi-Fi Crystal clock is 37.4 MHz.

The frequencies are a kind of spikes.

Can you let us know how we can solve this problem?
900 MHz can be ignored.

[image]

[image]

I am suspecting below things in the device

1. DDR and eMMC clock signals
2. FPC cables of MIPI display or MIPI camera

If the FPC cables are the problem, can you tell me how to shield the cables correctly and with which tape?
IF the board clocks are the problems, how to solve this problem?

Comment: Welcome! Please post schematic and layout. What's your PCB stackup, layer utilization and decoupling situation?

Comment: If you have your own test lab, then just start turning features off until you find out which is causing the problem. Once you find the module causing the bulk of the problem you can then look at solutions. Another option is to get out a near field probe and try to find what is generating those peaks, but this can be difficult if it's a tightly packed board. Unfortunately there is no simple solution to these problems. If you aren't confident it would be worth getting a consultant in (talk to your test house).

Comment: You either remove your antennas or source, is what I've been told before.

Comment: "900 MHz can be ignored" Why? That looks like an intentional radiator around 10mW ERP, I assume on the 902MHz for USA/FCC Part 15. If so the disturbances are somewhat likely coming from that one. And if so, test again with all intentional radiators disabled.

Comment: The lab told me that the peak at 900 MHz comes due to GSM mobile carrier in the area. So, whenever the control room door is opened, it peaks.

Comment: @ErikFriesen, that is right! To do this, from your experiences in the field, what could cause this frequency on the board or in the device? This information will be helpful. I gathered information about the operating frequencies on the board by actually measuring it. Main clock - 24M, WiFi clock - 37M, Display MIPI clock seems to be combination of frequencies, PWMs are not at that high frequency. eMMC clock - 200M, DDR clock - could not measure due to direct connection from SOC to DDR and no access due to BGA ICs.

Comment: There are FPC cables inside for display and camera. Others are 2 pin wires for LEDs, buttons, speakers, mic and vibrator. There are two antennas also for WIFI and BT.

Comment: Can you post photos and/or board layouts?  Its basically the only way you can get help in a place like this.

Comment: @HR86 I think you're misunderstanding how EMC is generated. The operating frequency of the bus/line is usually secondary to the rise/fall rate when it comes to pesky noise issues. Obviously high frequency lines require faster edge rates, but a low speed connection that is poorly designed can easily be the source of your issues. These can also become re-radiators for other signals in the system. It's not as simple as matching the frequency peaks to the clock speeds in your system to find the culprit.

Comment: @Jon, Yes, the rise and fall rates can also be the reason but I thought even the high-speed clock frequencies can also be the possible culprits. Do you suggest any method to check the problematic rise/fall rates in the circuit?